# KafkaConsumer poll() returns partition size of 0 every time after the 1st call

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Following the documentation at:
https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

I am using Manual Offset Control and am trying a simple test case with the commitSync() method to set the offset to a static value. Then, I want to call the poll() method again to consume from that offset. This should be handled with the while loop:

```
 try {
     while(true) {
         System.out.println("outer loop");
         ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
         System.out.println("partition size: " + records.partitions().size());

         for (TopicPartition partition : records.partitions()) {
             List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> partitionRecords = records.records(partition);
             for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : partitionRecords) {
                 System.out.println(record.offset() + ": " + record.value());

                 long offset = record.offset();
                 if (SOME CONDITION) {
                 consumer.commitSync(Collections.singletonMap(partition, new OffsetAndMetadata(offset+1)));
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 } finally {
   consumer.close();
 }
```

However, it looks like I always get partitions of size 0 after the 1st poll() call.

In my output I just see the following loop forever:

```
outer loop
partition size: 0
```

However, if I terminate my program and rerun it, I can see that the commitSync() worked and it starts reading from offset 6. I want to know how to do this without manually terminating and rerunning the program.

Comment: The solution that worked for me was to just instantiate a new KafkaConsumer